# Event Handling - sender as main class

Tags: c#, events

Apologies if the title is misleading, but I'm not sure precisely what to call what I'm looking for here. I have the following "main" class:

```
public class Entity : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public EntityRole Role { get; set; }         
    public EntityStats Stats = new EntityStats();
    //Other stuff.... 
}
```

And a ... sub class? (proper name would be appreciated for this) ... called `EntityStats`:

```
public class EntityStats : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public int CurrentHealth 
    {
        get { return _currentHealth; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _currentHealth)
            {
                _currentHealth = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentHealth");
            }
        } 
    }

    //other properties...

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, e);
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Where an `Entity` object contains a property of type `EntityStats`.

On the other side of my code, I'm registering an `Entity` object to listen for `PropertyChanged` events:

```
public void RegisterEntity(Entity entity)
{            
    entity.Stats.PropertyChanged += entity_PropertyChanged;           
}

void entity_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "CurrentHealth")
    {
        Message.Write("CurrentHealth property changed!");
        DeathCheck((Entity)sender);
    }
}
```

The issue I'm having is with `DeathCheck((Entity)sender);` -- Because the `CurrentHealth` `OnPropertyChanged` event is part of the `EntityStats` class, the object is of type `EntityStats`, which only contains part of the data I need.

How can I determine the `Entity` object that `sender` belongs to, **or** how can I refactor this code so that when a property inside `EntityStats` changes, an event is raised in the `Entity` class?

Comment: There are many ways to do it. Create a parent property in entitystat and store the entity object. This way you can access entitiy properties. However based on your requirement I think it would useful to expose the event from entity rather than entitystat.

Comment: @XtremeBytes Thanks for the comment. Can you offer an answer showing how to expose the event from the `Entity` class? Doing it this way makes the most sense to me, but I'm not quite sure how to implement it given that `CurrentHealth` is a property of `EntityStats`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can listen the EntityStats event's in Entity constructor and dispatch a Entity event's. Like this:

```
public class Entity : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Entity() {
        Stats.PropertyChanged += Stats_PropertyChanged
    }
    //Other stuff.... 

    void Stats_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            e.PropertyName = "Stats." + e.PropertyName;
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, in the **RegisterEntity**, the listener method can be associated direct to the Entity instance:

```
public void RegisterEntity(Entity entity)
{            
    entity.PropertyChanged += entity_PropertyChanged;           
}
```

and the sender of the listener method is Entity instance, but is possible identify if the property was changed in Stats property:

```
void entity_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "Stats.CurrentHealth")
    {
        Message.Write("Stats.CurrentHealth property changed!");
        DeathCheck((Entity)sender);
    }
}
```

Comment: So this registers the `Entity` object to listen to the `PropertyChanged` event on `EntityStats`?

Comment: Yes. In terms of coupling, Entity already have dependency of EntityStats. But EntityStats don't need have dependency of Entity.

Answer (score 1):

You could give the `EntityStats` class a property named `Entity` (or somesuch) and set that property in the `EntityStats` constructor:

```
public class Entity : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public EntityRole Role { get; set; }         
    public EntityStats Stats = new EntityStats(this);
    //Other stuff.... 
}

public class EntityStats : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Entity _entity;

    public Entity Entity
    {
        get { return _entity; }
    }

    public EntityStats(Entity entity)
    {
        _entity = entity;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer, that makes sense! From a design standpoint, is there any issue with having a sub class (or whatever `EntityStats` would be called in this case .. I don't know!) hold a reference to its parent?

Comment: Depends on whether you'd ever want to, e.g., share one `EntityStats` between two `Entity` objects or pass it around to code that shouldn't know about its parent.

Comment: Perhaps this is an issue of the way it's been designed to begin with - the basic idea for `EntityStats` was a collection of properties (`health`, `damage`, `defense`, etc.) that I factored out into a separate class instead of leaving them listed as properties on the `Entity` class.

Comment: Oh and no, `EntityStats` isn't a subclass of `Entity` in your example; it's just another class.  To be a subclass it would have to inherit from `Entity`, which would mean that every `EntityStats` object would have all the fields and methods found in the `Entity` class in addition to its own fields and methods.

Comment: All I can think to say is that an `Entity` object contains a property of type `EntityStats`. Is there a term for that sort of relationship? Or is it simply a property that happens to be of that type?

Comment: If you want to get all technical, you can read about "composition" and "aggregation": http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/oop-concepts/composition-and-aggregation.html

Comment: Thanks for indulging me! I appreciate all the info.